# What is the best way to deveop a movieplayer that acts like the Youtube one?

Tags: android, ios, youtube, mpmovieplayer

Hi i would develop a movieplayer that user drag down and it goes at the end of the screen (and viceversa). I already develop this with swipe down gesture, but the youtube movieplayer follow the user finger, so the user drag the player down (or up) while the movieplayer is resizing...

What is the best way to reach this behavior on ios and android?

Thanks!